# why doesnt 'dot' go at the end of the line when text-align:right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a RTL website. When imputing Persian text, the full-stop or point goes at the beginning of the last line of the paragraph, which it must be at the end of the paragraph.

CSS for RTL :

```
text-align:right;
float:right;
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bbr8C/

Check the demo please, in the demo, the paragraph is at the right but the full stop is at the beginning of the last line. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not RTL text - that just moves the text to the right hand side of the screen, but keeping the text LTR. What you want is actually:

```
p {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbr8C/2/

Comment: but the text is still in the left hand side. it must start from right.

Comment: @DanielJJ sorry, I had an old fiddle link there. Check now.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
<p dir= "rtl"></p>
```

Or this in the CSS:

```
p{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the entire page is in a RTL language, set the direction on the `body` element:

```
<body dir=rtl>
```

If just one paragraph is in a RTL language, it naturally suffices to set direction on it:

```
<p dir=rtl>
```

The HTML [`dir` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#dir) is preferable to the CSS `direction` property, since text directionality is an inherent part of its structure rather than a casual presentational suggestion. As the MDN document says: “As the directionality of the text is semantically related to its content and not to its presentation, it is recommended that web developers use this attribute instead of the related CSS properties when possible. That way, the text will display correctly even on a browser that doesn't support CSS or has the CSS deactivated.”

Setting `dir=rtl` sets default right alignment, too, so you don’t need to set `text-align: right`.

Generally, browsers render texts using the directionality of characters as defined in properties of characters in Unicode. This is why a passage of text in Persian is shown correctly even without directionality settings. However, the directionality rules are complicated and do not always lead to correct rendering without some help. In this case, the paragraph ends with the period, which is directionally neutral, so with the default directionality (left to right) it gets misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

{text-align: right;
direction: ltr;}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

change your css to this :

```
p{
    text-align:left; //left now
    float:right;
}
```